# Yammer getLoginStatus fails with a 401 in Chrome

Tags: yammer

I have registered my App and set the Javascript origin to include my domain. But when I call yam.getLoginStatus in chrome, I get a 401, although I'm logged in.

Here's my test page (app id obfuscated):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.yammer.com/assets/platform_js_sdk.js">        </script>
</head>
<body>
<span id="yammer-login"></span>
<script> 
yam.config({appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"});
yam.connect.loginButton('#yammer-login', function (resp) {
    if (resp.authResponse) { 
        console.log(resp);
        document.getElementById('yammer-login').innerHTML = 'Welcome to Yammer!'; 
        yam.getLoginStatus(function(response){console.log(response);}, true);
    }
}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In chrome, on loading the page, I see:

```
GET https://www.yammer.com/platform/login_status.json?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&_=1407286964912 401 (Unauthorized)
```

And when clicking the login button, the output I get in the console window is:

```
Object {access_token: Object, success: true, status: "connected", authResponse: true}
GET https://www.yammer.com/platform/login_status.json?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&_=1407286968658 401 (Unauthorized) 
Object {status: "notConnected", access_token: "", perms: ""}
```

In other words, the login button works (I do get a valid response.authResponse); but when I immediately ask if I'm logged in, I get a 401.

I'm obviously doing something wrong... any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, figured it out. Yammer requires that the user has third party cookies enabled in their browser... which I tend to disagree with, but whatever! Enabling third party cookies fixed this problem.

Comment: Enabling third party cookies fixed a similar problem for me: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23248749/1958200